# Assign user's input to a variable

Tags: c#

I've cut the code down into this small piece so it would be easier to read. My problem is that the value that the user writes into "injtaille" doesn't transfer over to the switch a little lower down. How can I fix this?

```
if (inj == "oui")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Quel est la taille de l'injection? (30 - 50 - 60) ");
    injtaille = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
switch (client)
{
    case 1:
       consprix = 25;
       imgradprix = 55;
       analyzeprix = 28;
       switch (injtaille)
       {
           case 30
       }
```

Comment: The `case 30` is missing a `:` and the code to be executed.  What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Are you getting errors did you try a default case for the switch statement

Comment: @Roy Yes I am aware that there is no `:` after `case 30`. The problem is that when I put my cursor on `switch (injtaille)`, it says that I'm using an unassigned value.

Comment: You should accept the answer of @MickyD. You may also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710485/c-sharp-use-of-unassigned-local-variable) posted in 2011, with many other answers.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that when I put my cursor on switch (injtaille), it says that I'm using an unassigned value

You need to *initialise* your variables before using them.  Your original code (from what I can see) only sets it if the guard `inj == "oui"` holds true.

Try this:

```
int injtaille =0; // default value here

if (inj == "oui")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Quel est la taille de l'injection? (30 - 50 - 60) ");
    injtaille = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
switch (client)
{
    case 1:
       consprix = 25;
       imgradprix = 55;
       analyzeprix = 28;
       switch (injtaille)
       {
           case 30:
              ....
       }
```

Depending on the logic on your program, it's generally a good idea to include a `default` in your `switch` statements too.

Comment: Alright so, the default starting value of injtaille will be 0. Let's say I write in 50 at the ReadLine line, will `injtaille` take on the value of whatever the user writes in the ReadLine?

Comment: @Dr.Roflcopter yes it is.

Comment: @Dr.Roflcopter Yes, it will as you can easily see by running the code

Comment: @Dr.Roflcopter You're missing a `break;`  _right at the end_ after the `}`